# append several Pandas dataframe on top of each other in the same excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

I have two dataframes with labels, I want to append or concat them at bottom of each other

```
d = {}
d['first_level'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['idx', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                                 data=[[10, 1, 2, 3],
                                       [20, 4, 5, 6]]).set_index('idx')

d['first_level2'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['idx', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                                 data=[[10, 1, 2, 3],
                                       [20, 4, 5, 6]]).set_index('idx')

    df_final = pd.concat(d, axis=1,)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx')
            # df_final.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
            # ddf_finalf=df_final.drop(['idx'],axis=1)
            df_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_analysis', index=True,)
        
        writer.save()
```

I have this code, this results in excel output like this:

```
 first_level  first_level2 
 idx a b c     idx a b c
  10 1 2 3      10 1 2 3
  20 4 5 5      20 4 5 5
```

However I want `first_level2` at bottom of `first_level`,and the excel output should be like this:

```
first_level  
idx a b c 
10 1 2 3 
20 4 5 6 

first_level2 
idx a b c
10 1 2 3
20 4 5 5
```

I tried with MultiIndex too, but got the same results,How can I achieve this using pandas I want to such output in excel, I tried looking into docs but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: You problem is unclear. `df1` and `df` are not defined here.

Comment: did u try with `axis=0`?

Comment: can you provide the constructor for the output? You cannot have *in data* headers

Comment: `pd.concat(d)`?

Comment: tried, it doesn't work @Corralien

Comment: can you explain in detail @mozway

Comment: "*doesn't work*" doesn't mean anything unless you clearly show what you expect, the provided output as text is not a valid dataframe, can you provide the expected output as a DataFrame like you did for the input?

Comment: I want to dataframe to be added bottom, so when converted to excel I get the expected output in excel format. @mozway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append each dataframe with a custom header into an excel sheet, you can use a loop to add each DataFrame successively with help of [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) and the `skiprow` option of [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx')
start = 0
for k, df in d.items():
    df2 = pd.concat({k: df}, axis=1)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', startrow=start)
    start += len(df)+df.columns.nlevels+int(bool(df.index.name))+1
writer.save()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: is there any way I can Increase size of text of `first_level` and `first_level1` ?

Comment: @Shubham I tried to think of all the items that could use space but it's not fully tested, don't hesitate to give feedback. As the position is manually computed I could have missed something and this would overwrite part of the previous tables

Comment: Regarding the formatting, it's out of the scope of this question (and I don't know)

Answer (score 0):

as answered by Epsi95, axis should be 0

```
import pandas as pd
d = {}
d['first_level'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['idx', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                                 data=[[10, 1, 2, 3],
                                       [20, 4, 5, 6]]).set_index('idx')

d['first_level2'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['idx', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                                 data=[[10, 1, 2, 3],
                                       [20, 4, 5, 6]]).set_index('idx')
df_final = pd.concat(d, axis=0,)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx')
        # df_final.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        # ddf_finalf=df_final.drop(['idx'],axis=1)
df_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='my_analysis', index=True,)
    
writer.save()
```

Comment: with `axis=0` the labels `first_level` and `first_level2` , are on left side of columns, I want them at top of the their respective rows and columns, like in question.